# Overriding block in magento does not work

Tags: magento

Top menu is not building through custom code. it built by the default main code. please help me out.

app\code\local\Mynav\Mytopmenu\etc\config.xml

```
<global>

      <blocks>
        <mytopmenu>
            <rewrite>
                <html_topmenu>Mynav_Mytopmenu_Block_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
            </rewrite>
        </mytopmenu>
    </blocks>

</global>
```

app\code\local\Mynav\Mytopmenu\Block\Html\Topmenu.php

```
<?php

class Mynav_Mytopmenu_Block_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Top menu data tree
     *
     * @var Varien_Data_Tree_Node
     */
    protected $_menu;

    /**
     * Init top menu tree structure
     */
    public function _construct()
    {

        $this->_menu = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node(array(), 'root', new Varien_Data_Tree());
    }

    /**
     * Get top menu html
     *
     * @param string $outermostClass
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHtml($outermostClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
    {

        Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before', array(
            'menu' => $this->_menu
        ));

        $this->_menu->setOutermostClass($outermostClass);
        $this->_menu->setChildrenWrapClass($childrenWrapClass);

        $html = $this->_getHtml($this->_menu, $childrenWrapClass);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_after', array(
            'menu' => $this->_menu,
            'html' => $html
        ));

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass)
    {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        foreach ($children as $child) {

            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . ' >';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . ' onclick=alert("hitop");><span>'
                . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . 'jain</span></a>';

            if ($child->hasChildren()) {
                if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                    $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
                }
                $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
                $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
                $html .= '</ul>';

                if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }
            }
            $html .= '</li>';

            $counter++;
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Generates string with all attributes that should be present in menu item element
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $item
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getRenderedMenuItemAttributes(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $item)
    {
        $html = '';
        $attributes = $this->_getMenuItemAttributes($item);

        foreach ($attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $html .= ' ' . $attributeName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attributeValue) . '"';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's attributes
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemAttributes(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $item)
    {
        $menuItemClasses = $this->_getMenuItemClasses($item);
        $attributes = array(
            'class' => implode(' ', $menuItemClasses)
        );

        return $attributes;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's classes
     *
     * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemClasses(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $item)
    {
        $classes = array();

        $classes[] = 'level' . $item->getLevel();
        $classes[] = $item->getPositionClass();

        if ($item->getIsFirst()) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }

        if ($item->getIsActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }

        if ($item->getIsLast()) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }

        if ($item->getClass()) {
            $classes[] = $item->getClass();
        }

        if ($item->hasChildren()) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        return $classes;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The parent element of `<rewrite>` must be named like the code of the **original** module, not like your own one. Magento can't know, **what** you want to rewrite otherwise.

```
<blocks>
    <page>
        <rewrite>
            <html_topmenu>Mynav_Mytopmenu_Block_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
        </rewrite>
    </page>
</blocks>
```